# Get all urls indexed to google from a website

Tags: url, web-crawler

I want a program that does that, from a website, get all the urls indexed to it with a good output, like, all the urls line by line, and get the urls not used in the website (because a spider can already do that).

I have been searching and finding sloopy options, what I want is accurate and simple: INPUT: URL OUTPUT: ALL THE URLS.

Comment: What do you mean under "urls not used in the website"?

Comment: I mean urls there are no links in the web

Comment: Do you need a webcrawler that crawls a website, and shows links indexed and not indexed by a search engine?

Comment: I meant indexed (at use and not at use) by not at use I mean for example a test servlet on a website u cannot access through any link, but still is indexed to google for example. I need a webcrawler that extracts as much info as possible, preferible a command line one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know such applications for now, but I'll try to simplify your task by dividing it:

1. Yon need a list of your website's internal links. Any webcrawler tool can do that.
2. You need a list of your website's pages indexed by *Google*. There are a lot of SE index checkers, you can google it.
3. Compare *2nd* list to the *1st* one, and find all the links presents in Google's index but missing on your website.

Comment: Well much easier, I found a programm in Kale called "golismero" really fancy on that matter, thank anyways for ur anser

Answer (score 0):

This is old but it shows a number one on google. If you need to find all the urls in google just type

```
site:domain.com
```

Comment: Google site searches don't show all the pages from a site, but a representative sample.  A site search may also may show URLs that don't appear in other searches such as redirecting URLs.